# Send PUSHBULLET Notifications from a specific app to airtable via make.com

Tags: pushbullet

I am looking to set up a scenario via make.com to send specific notifications from an app on my samsung phone to my google sheet and/or airtable with a make.com flow.

Would anyone know how to set up the http requests so I can collect specific notifications via make.com?

Thanks

I have tried to set up an http request but do not know how to receive the notifications which should get triggered with ever new notification that is received on the phone

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would want to poll the https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes endpoint to get pushes. You can set up an HTTP module to send a get request 15 minutes (or however often you need). You also could add a data store to the scenario to log previous responses so you can filter out any old pushes before adding them to your air table.

If you're having problems getting the HTTP module to function it may have something to do with Pushbullet's authentication. See the linked image for how to add your auth token to the request. Hope this helps!
[image: Pushbullet HTTP Module]